# Restrict access of a K8s secret to a particular service account

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets, k8s-serviceaccount, k8s-rolebinding

I have a secret which contains very sensitive information.
I want to make sure that this secret can only be accessed by a certain service account and nobody else.

Using RBAC, I can tell which user can access which resources. But is there some way where I can tell that this secret can only be accessed by this user?

Answer (score 2):

- as far as i know , There is no straight forward way to get that info (might require write a script to that iterates through rolebindings & clusterrolebindings).
- Recently found a plugin called `kubectl who-can` on [kubectl-who-can](https://github.com/aquasecurity/kubectl-who-can) that fetches those kind details with one command.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get it done with Validating webhook where the API request fields are parsed and checked for matching users.
[OPA](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/) can be used to do some heavy lifting.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).